# Arduino standard libraries location

Tags: library, core-libraries

I want to read the source code of an arduino library that comes with the IDE. 
Specifically the GSM.h

I dont know the location of the standard libraries that come with the IDE.

I only know the location of the user installed libraries.

So where is the source code of GSM.h?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i found out the location.
In Win 7, it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries

Comment: Those are the standard libraries. If you want to add libraries, it's (I think) preferred to add them to the `My Documents\Arduino\libraries\` folder.

Comment: Definitely preferred. Otherwise you lose your user-installed libraries when you upgrade to the next version.